# Add to Array Collection Many to Many self Referencing Api Platform - Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many, api-platform.com

i have a user entity with a Many to Many self-referencing relation. It gives me 2 properties:
myFriends and friendsWithMe (like described in the Doctrine documentation) and with methods like addFriendsWithMe, removeFriendsWithMe,...

Both properties are array Collection.

In Api Platform, if i do something like this when updating my User entity (patch Api/users/1):

```
{
"friendsWithMe": [
"api/users/2"
]
}
```

it's working but if i want to do the same to add another user (api/users/3) to the friendsWithMe of User 1, it's not adding to the array but instead removing user/2 and replacing it with user/3.

In a regular Symfony Controller, if i do :

```
$user->addFriendsWithMe($otherUser);
```

It's working perfectly well and i can add as many users as i want (they're not replaced).

Feels like with Api Platform it's not detecting the add* method and instead use remove and insert.

Any idea about this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. You must to pass an array containing all user your need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it seems weird to me because it means each time i want to add a new user, i have to fetch all previous one and add them  all again to the new array for insert ? it seems not very logical to my point of view.

Comment: I'm sorry for your point of view. So in your opinion, when dealing with the given object `{"age": 21}`, then updating it with `{"age": 1}`, you expect that the result is `{"age": 22}` right ?

Comment: hum no but i would expect something like [ {"age":21}, {"age":1} ] and each time i push a new object to my array, add it to the array and not replace everything (like what happens in my case). I think i misunderstand something ^^

Answer (score 1):

You need to use adders and removers instead of getters/setters (though you still need a getter).

Lets say you got:

```
// Annotation
private array $friends;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->friends = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

"Normally" you'd create a getter (`return $this->friends`) and a setter (`$this->friends = $friends`).

However, with an `array` (ArrayCollection) you will want to be able to add/remove single records.

So, delete the setter, replace it with an adder and a remover.

All up it becomes:

```
// Annotation
private array $friends;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->friends = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getFriends(): array
{
    return $this->friends->toArray();
}

public function addFriend(Friend $friend): void
{
    if(! $this->friends->contains($friend) {
        $this->friends->add($friend);
    }
}

public function removeFriend(Friend $friend): void
{
    if($this->friends->contains($friend) {
        $this->friends->removeElement($friend);
    }
}
```

Have a look at [Doctrine Many To Many](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional) documentation.

Also have a read of [Handling Relations](https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/handling-relations/) of Api-Platform.

Make sure you avoid setting the serialization configuration for a collection / item endpoint to serialize endless loops. (So only allow one-way inclusion of whole entities on endpoints (e.g. the owning side) to avoid a Friend->Friend->Friend->Friend->infinity loop)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and the explanations but i already have a "adder" because (like said in my first post), in php i'm able to do : $user->addFriendsWithMe($otherUser);
The problem here, is that Api Platform calls removeFriend before adding a new one( if i already have many friends in my array, Api Platform remove all of them). Maybe i should ask them directly why it's behave like this.

Comment: Please check then that you adder does not call the remove function in your entity? Or that you maybe do that on the inverse side? Think is: AP does not call remover before adder internally, so this must be an error in your code, somewhere. Could you maybe have a check of the configuration and / or any listeners you might be using ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common problem with Api Platform, indeed patch and put requests to any OneToMany or ManyToMany relationship is considered as a replacement (thus it wouldn't just append the new relationship).

Try these :

- You might want to create a custom operation (a custom endpoint that actually *does* append your new relationship, for instance a POST request to `/api/users/{id}/friends` with a body containing the new "friends" IRIs to append).
- OR you might try doing the inverse relationship (well, in your case I don't think it might be successfull since it's a ManyToMany relationship, but you might want to do that next time you have a OneToMany or ManyToOne relationship).

It would be great that API Platform proposed a fix on that, but I'm afraid it's not really incoming (and not *really* a bug, just a different point of view).